# Docker-compose pull not working over ssh?

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

I have a laptop with docker desktop. When I try to run "docker-compose pull" I get the following error:

error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out:` A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.``

If I run the same command on the laptop it pulls with no problem. Over ssh other commands work well.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `"credsStore": "secretservice"` line from the docker config file, if you do not need it. Then the login should go smoothly